# Algorithm for finding maximum number of valid combinations?

Tags: algorithm, combinations, maximize

OK... so I have a bit of a tricky one (for me, at least).

I have a list of simple objects and I need to figure out how to find a combination that makes use of the maximum number.  Each of these objects' classes have a property (string) for their name, a property (List) for the other elements' names with which they like to bond, and a property (List) for the other elements' names with which they do not like to bond.

If an element is added to a collection where that specific element "likes" one (or more) of the other elements already in the collection then the added element returns a score of +1 for each item in the collection that it likes.  Likewise, a score of -1 is returned for each other element in the collection the added element does not like.  After adding all the elements to the final collection, the score for each must be >= 0.

How would I go about find the combination(s) of elements I can use that will return the largest collection?  In the event of multiple combinations returning an equal number of elements, all possible combinations should be returned.

I hope that made sense...  Also, I'm using C# (.NET 4.0) but any programming language can be used, I just need to figure out the logic behind it.

Thanks in advance,
Sonny

Comment: Is there a finite collection of objects or a specific range of objects that you are looking at? Can a single object be repeated in a collection?

Comment: Also, are the 'like' and 'dislike' lists predefined and fixed for each item and do they have the same length for all items? If the lengths differ, you might try sorting the items by popularity before adding them.

Comment: Are the relationships symmetric? I mean If A likes B, does it mean the B likes A, and if A dislikes B, does it mean the B dislikes A?

Comment: @jball - The initial size of the collection can be arbitrary and the results list can use as many or as few of the initial elements as necessary.  The final results list can only only contain unique elements.

Comment: @500 - Internal Server Error - The likes and dislikes are static and determined prior to runtime.

Comment: @Lior Kogan - They are not symetric, but if one element "likes" another, then the second element will never "dislike" the first (though it may not "like" the first).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you are right to say that this is a tricky problem. I think of objects as nodes in a graph and the like/dislike info as giving weights to links between nodes. Ignore the "like" field and give all links weight 0 or weight -1. In this case, your problem is to find the maximum number of nodes, such that all of the links between them have weight 0, and none of them have weight -1. Suppose that you have a program to do this efficiently.

Now look at the problem http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_problem, which is a known hard problem. If you have a max clique problem, then create links between all nodes. Where the two nodes were linked in max clique make the weight 0. Where a link did not exist, make the weight -1. Now run a program to solve your problem, and you have solved max clique. So I think your problem is NP-Complete, and there is very unlikely to be an efficient solution to it.

Comment: Thanks, that wiki atricle was exactly what I was trying to explain.  I'm only dealing with between a dozen or two dozen nodes at most and so I think I'll try to brute force it and see how the performance turns out.